# Convert date from mm/dd/yyyy to yyyymmdd

Tags: c#, .net

What I want is when user input text in textbox in date format, text change to string. for example when user enters 9/25/2012 I have to store it as 20120925.
Help would be appreciated

Comment: Use DateTime.ParseExact, then yourParsedDateTime.ToString("your format")

Comment: ToString("yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Answer (score 7):

```
string converted = DateTime.ParseExact(strInput, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                  .ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

Comment: You should almost certainly specify the invariant culture here.

Comment: I would escape the `/`, like `\\/`, or use the InvariantCulture in the `ParseExact`.

Comment: Unless the OP specifies what is his storage (DB, text file, etc.), I would suggest him to use this code. If he wants to store in a DB, he shouldn't have to deal with string conversion, but directly use the DateTime struct with SqlParameters.

Answer (score 1):

```
string str = blackOutFromDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

Answer (score 1):

`fileName` contains that date string. So, I split the `fileName` using an empty string as a delimiter, to get the `expectedDate`.

I then split the `expectedDate` using "-" as delimiter and convert it to `datetime`.

```
string[] splitFileName = fileName.Split(' ');
string expectedDate = (splitFileName[1]);
string[] dateparts = expectedDate.Split('-');
expextedDate = dateparts[1] + "-" + dateparts[0] + "-" + dateparts[2]; 
DateTime CallDate = Convert.ToDateTime(expextedDate);
```

Comment: 1)filename contains that datestring .2) i have used split and took that date string to the expextedDate . 3)i have again used split method. this way you will surely convert any date string . happy coding :)

Comment: please consider adding some clarification

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.DateTime` class

```
var date = Convert.ToDateTime(textBox1.Text);
textBox1.Text = date.Year + "" + date.Month + date.Day;
```

Comment: @Desolator - What ken2k meant that year, month and day are int fields. And what you are doing is adding them. This would throw exception as text is a string/text field. Use ToString() with each field.

Comment: this code won't compile. You can't add int and string (it's not javascript ;))

Comment: @SteveB It will compile successfully!! `When you add a string to an int, Int32.ToString() will be invoked implicitly, resulting in a characters representation of the number`

Comment: I've learn something. Has it been always the case with .Net? or is this conversion possible only possible starting from a specific .Net version ?

Comment: @SteveB It is always the case of .NET

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var date = DateTime.Parse("9/25/2012");
var modified = string.format("{0}{1}{2}", date.Year, date.Month, date.Day);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it worked for me.

```
 DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(txtFrom.Text);
 string date = Convert.ToDateTime(dt).ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```